# Multiple AppDomain with Web-based Management Consoles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, appdomain, applicationhost

I am thinking about a system that is based on plugins. I am going to create my plugins in each AppDomain and talk with them via Name Pipes in WCF. But I also want each of my plugins have some sort of management console in asp.net mvc and one management console for my system.

How can I implement such a system? So they are on seperate processes. (System on Window Services and Management Console on IIS)

I was thinking about using **ApplicationHost** in each plugins so I can manage them from there.

Also my system needs to be up as long as possible so I don't want to put it and run it on IIS.

Are there any advices for such a system?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing extensible application with plugins, you can find [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) from MS very useful.